# React Native Webview not working when loading html / script

Tags: javascript, html, react-native

I am trying to load a widget using the `react-native-webview' library. I believe I am doing this right but the widget is not loading, I have tried to set breakpoints on the webview itself and it looks like its building, any advice?

```
<WebView
          source={{
            html: `<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

              <body>
              <script src="https://widgets.coingecko.com/coingecko-coin-price-marquee-widget.js"></script>
              <coingecko-coin-price-marquee-widget  coin-ids="bitcoin,ethereum,eos,ripple,litecoin" currency="usd" background-color="#ffffff" locale="en">
              </coingecko-coin-price-marquee-widget>
              </body>
            </html>`,
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - I needed to give a width to the react-native-webview .